# How to get frame line at the last element of array

Tags: c

I have a question regarding my code. I want to print a playfield which looks like this:

```
|     |
|     |
|     |
|     |
-12345-
```

This is my code:

```
void PrintBoard(char* argv[])
{
  int width_of_gamefield = atoi(argv[2]);
  int height_of_gamefield = atoi(argv[3]);
  
 
  for(int j = 0; j <= height_of_gamefield -1; j++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", "|");
  }
  printf("%s", "-");
  for(int i = 1; i <= width_of_gamefield; i++)
  {
    printf("%d", i);
  }
  printf("%s", "-");
}
```

And what i get is this:

```
|
|
|
|
-12345-
```

How do i print the right side?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
  for(int j = 0; j < height_of_gamefield; j++)
  {
    printf("%s%*s\n","|", width_of_gamefield,"|");
  }
```

The %*s allows you to specify a variable number for the string padding.